# PyPI personal module cannot be imported by other users or myself?

Tags: python, module, pypi

I am currently working on a rather simply Python module and I've been trying to publish it on PyPI all day. This is my first time doing it.

I've succesfully built it using `python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel` then done `python3 -m twine upload --repository testpypi dist/*` and `twine upload dist/*` and it is successfully uploaded as seen [here](https://pypi.org/project/manhattandistance/).
However, when me or my friends do `pip install manhattandistance` it installs the package, and when I try to import it using from `manhattan distance import *` as seen in my code:

```
from manhattandistance import *
print(mandist(37.99438337141694, 23.732534940640544, 37.97163377228043, 23.72572774064004))
```

However, it says that **`Import "manhattan_distance" could not be resolved`**. When I try reinstalling it using pip, it says that it already is installed, and when I make my way to that path I notice that only a .info is installed, while other modules have 2 folders, one with files inside and one for .info.

Screenshot from powershell:
[image: Screenshot from powershell]

See that my module only has a .info folder dedicated?:
[image: See that my module only has a .info folder dedicated]

**I created all the necessary files:**

```
-manhattandistance
--src
---__init.py
--LICENSE.txt
--CHANGELOG.txt
--READDME.md
--setup.py
```

**My setup.py**

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
 
with open("README.md", "r", encoding="utf-8") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()
 
setup(
  name='manhattandistance',
  py_modules=["manhattandistance"],
  version='1.0.3',
  description='Calculates the Manhattan Distance of two places',
  long_description=open('README.md').read() +  open('CHANGELOG.txt').read(),
  long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
  url='http://packages.python.org/manhattandistance',  
  author='NAME',
  author_email='MAIL',
  license='MIT License', 
  classifiers=[
  'Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable',
  'Intended Audience :: Education',
  'Operating System :: Microsoft :: Windows :: Windows 10',
  'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
  'Programming Language :: Python :: 3'
                ],
  keywords='distance', 
  package_dir={'':'src'},
)
```

**My **init**.py**

```
def mandist(lat_from, lon_from, lat_to, lon_to):
    from math import cos
    phi_m = 3.141592653589793/180 * (lat_from + lat_to) / 2
    lat_k = 111.13209 - 0.56605 * cos(2 * phi_m) + 0.00120 * cos(4 * phi_m)
    lon_k = 111.41513 * cos(phi_m) - 0.0945 * cos(3 * phi_m) + 0.00012*cos(5 * phi_m)
    fin_lat = (lat_from - lat_to) * lat_k
    fin_lon = (lon_from - lon_to) * lon_k
    return abs(fin_lon) + abs(fin_lat)
```

Comment: `py_modules=["manhattandistance"],` implies you have a module `manhattandistance.py` which you don't actually have. In directory `src/` there have to be a package subdirectory but there is no one. To use said package subdirectory there should be command `packages=…` in `setup.py`. My advice is to read carefully the packaging tutorial at https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/, restructure files/directories and rewrite `setup.py`.

Comment: So, you recommend I change py_modules=["utils"]? (That's how I'm naming it now, as Mattia recommended.
Also, is it necessary to have src/ and subdirectories?

Comment: "*`py_modules=["utils"]`*" Yes, if you have `utils.py`. "*is it necessary to have src/ and subdirectories?*" No if you don't have package(s).

Comment: Alright, I pushed the updated and I'm waiting for feedback from my friend who's betatesting. Another question, is it possible to make it as if I don't have to use something.mandist (such as utils) and only use from manhattandistance import * (instead of excplicity mentioning utils?)

Comment: If I don't have the module folder in the same folder as the program I'm testing, it simply doesn't work (like other modules do). I get ""ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'manhattandistance'"" although I have installed it through pip...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:
`import manhattandistance`

And then use as follow:
`manhattandistance.mandist()`

ps: I suggest to have another file instead of putting it in the `__init__.py`

EDIT:

Place your code in a `utils.py` file. You will have a structure like this:

```
manhattandistance/
    src/
        __init__.py
        utils.py
    LICENSE.txt
    CHANGELOG.txt
    READDME.md
    setup.py
```

Change your settings by replacing `package_dir` to `packages=setuptools.find_packages()` (should be enough)

```py
    setup(
      name='manhattandistance',
      version='1.0.3',
      description='Calculates the Manhattan Distance of two places',
      long_description=open('README.md').read() +  open('CHANGELOG.txt').read(),
      long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
      url='http://packages.python.org/manhattandistance',  
      author='Dionysios Rigatos',
      author_email='dion.rigatos@gmail.com',
      license='MIT License', 
      classifiers=[
      'Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable',
      'Intended Audience :: Education',
      'Operating System :: Microsoft :: Windows :: Windows 10',
      'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
      'Programming Language :: Python :: 3'
                    ],
      keywords='distance', 
      packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    )
```

then you should be able to import the module with:

`from manhattandistance.src.utils import mandist`

Comment: Thanks for answering!

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'manhattandistance'

Please take a look at the part that it looks like pip install manhattandistance is not installing all the necessary files, Picture#2.

Comment: Just to exclude erros, try to create a new file called `utils.py` and place there your code. Then reinstall the package and import it with `from  manhattandistance.utils import mandist`

Comment: Within the .src folder or should I just get rid of it and have everything in the main manhattandistance folder (from utils.py to README etc)?

Comment: I change the my answer, please try with it and let me know :)

Comment: Subfolder named manhattandistance inside the main folder named manhattandistance? Screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/6N4VRR7

Comment: you can give to it the name you like my was an example. You can keep the structure that you had before. Answer updated

Comment: Yep, everything worked perfectly. Thank you for your help! I have another question; Is it possible to avoid utils.py and use: from manhattandistance import *, so I don't have to use utils.mandist(x,x,x,x) ?

Comment: Glad that now it works, but having an import with `*` is not the best approach, because if you will update the `__init__.py` file, you can risk to import un-wanted library in you code. If you wanto to not call `utils.mandist()` you can easy place `utils` in the import statement (like in the example) `from manhattandistance.src.utils import mandist`